# PhpStorm runs only JavaScript instead of PHP?

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have just installed fresh PhpStorm on Mac. I set my interpreter and so on. I can create `.php` files. But when I run it runs only JavaScript and there is no option to run php? How can I fix this?

> Run 'filename.php (JavaScript...)'

Same with debug. How this can be fixed?

Comment: Have you created a run configuration for PHP?

Comment: @Don'tPanic sorry but how do i do that?

Comment: Go to `Run->Edit Configurations...` and add a configuration for PHP. There are some templates there you can work from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've configured PhpStorm to handle files with `.php` extension as JavaScript code rather than PHP.

Open the settings dialog (*File/ Settings*), head to *Editor/ File Types* and review the *Recognized File Types* section:

- Remove `*.php` from *JavaScript*.
- Make sure that *PHP* contains `*.php`.
- Remove any other unwanted registered pattern, such as `filename.php`.